# Error in SQL statement with inserting

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to insert user inputted data into database, but am getting the error "Syntax error: Encountered "[" at line 1, column 160." Here is my code, what am I doing wrong?`

```
if (action.getSource() == Submit_button)
{
    try
    {
        sql = "INSERT INTO Customer (FNAME, LNAME, AGE, LICNUM, STATE, CAR_TYPE, RENTDATE, RETURNDATE, TOTAL, PAYTYPE, RETURNED) VALUES(";
        sql = sql + "'" + f_name.getText() + "'" + "," + "'" + l_name.getText() + "'" + "," + Age + "," + "'" + liscense_num.getText() + "'" + "," + "'" 
            + issuing.getText() + "'" + "," + "'" + car_select.getToolkit() + "'" + "," + "'" + rental.getText() + "'" + "," + "'" + return_d.getText() + "'"
            + "," + total.getText() + "," + "'" + button_val.getText() + "'" + "," + "'true'" + ")"; 
        myStatement.execute(sql);
        System.out.print("Record has Been added to database");
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: post the stack trace

Answer (score 1):

can you change query into this?

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Customer (FNAME, LNAME, AGE, LICNUM, STATE, CAR_TYPE, RENTDATE, RETURNDATE, TOTAL, PAYTYPE, RETURNED) VALUES('"+f_name.getText()+"','"+l_name.getText()+"','"+Age+"','"+liscense_num.getText()+"','"+issuing.getText()+"','"+car_select.getToolkit()+"','"+rental.getText()+"','"+return_d.getText()+"','"+total.getText()+"','"+button_val.getText()+"','true') ";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--Not an answer:

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "[" at line 1, column 160.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at Auto.actionPerformed(Auto.java:381)
    at java.awt.Button.processActionEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Button.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "[" at line 1, column 160.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ParserImpl.parseStatementOrSearchCondition(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ParserImpl.parseStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
    ... 25 more
```